# Dice role probability. Why is my code showing an error message after I run the program?

Tags: java, probability, dice

I'm receiving this error message for my dice probability program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
at dice.dice.rollDie(dice.java:35)
at dice.dice.main(dice.java:20)
```

These are the lines that have errors:

line 13:int size = inputLine.nextInt();

line 35:return rolls;

line 20:roll2 = rollDie(roll2,size);

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class dice 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String answer = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number of rolls");
        Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);             
        int size = inputLine.nextInt(); 

        int[] roll1 = new int [13];
        int[] roll2 = new int [13];
        int[] total = new int [13]; 
        int[] sum = new int[13];
        roll1 = rollDie(roll1, size);
        roll2 = rollDie(roll2,size);
        total = findsum(roll1, roll2,total,size);
        sum = tossSum(sum,total,size);
        displaySum(total,size);
        System.out.println("Continue? y/n");
    } while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));

}


public static int[] rollDie(int[] rolls, int number)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        rolls[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    return rolls;
}



public static int[] findsum(int[] roll1, int[] roll2, int[] total,int number)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        total[i] = roll1[i] + roll2[i];
    return total;
 }



public static int[] tossSum(int[] sum, int[] total, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        total[sum[i]]++;
    return total;
}



public static void displaySum(int[] total, int number)
{
    System.out.println("Toss \t Count \t probability");
    double  k = number;
    for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + total[i] + "\t" + (total[i] / k * 100) + "%");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `size` after this line `int size = inputLine.nextInt();`?

Comment: It only blows up for me if I input a size > 13 (as one would expect).

Answer (score 1):

You create your arrays for the results with a fixed size of 13:

```
int[] roll1 = new int [13];
```

But you let the user enter a number of rolls which could be greater than 13.
This leads to the index out of bound error.

You should create the array with the correct size:

```
int[] roll1 = new int [size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared an array of size 13 so the index goes from 0 to 12. I think you tried to roll 14 dice, you should put a test before : `line 20:roll2 = rollDie(roll2,size);`
For example : `if (size > roll2.size()) { System.out.pritln("error : size too big"); return;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = inputLine.nextInt();
```

Is probably returning 13, which is the size of your array, but when you use that number to access an index of the array you should be doing `rollDie(roll2,size-1);`. In order to get the last position of the array.